# Printing numbers matrix pattern in C language using nested for loops advanced/moderate debugging

Tags: c, debugging

THIS IS TO PRINT THE NUMBER MATRIX PATTERN
hey there I want my code to print numbers in

```
    1 2 3 4 5
    5 1 2 3 4            
    4 5 1 2 3
    3 4 5 1 2
    2 3 4 5 1
    1 2 3 4 5
```

but my code is printing it in

```
    1 2 3 4 5
    2 4 3 5 1
    3 4 5 1 2
    4 5 1 2 3
    5 1 2 3 4
    1 2 3 4 5
```

this manner can you please help me solve this issue?
THIS IS MY SOURCE CODE WHICH I HAVE USED TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM CAN YOU PLEASE HELP ME DEBUG THIS?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    system("clear");
    int i,j,n,k=1,l=1;
        printf("Enter the value of n\n");
           scanf("%d",&n);
        for(i=1;i<=n+1;i++)
        {
            for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
             {
                k = i+j-1;
                if(k>n)
                   k-=n;
                printf("%d ",k);
        }
        printf("\n");
     }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why can you not debug it?

Comment: I tried @MartinJames but every time I tried i would get the same output I mentioned. I had the answer I just had it in the reverse order and that frustrated me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter the value of n\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int val = 0;
    for (int rows = 0; rows <= n; ++rows)
    {
        for (int cols = 0; cols < n; ++cols)
        {
            printf("%d ", val % n + 1);
            ++val;
        }
        printf("\n");
        --val;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Since the value just rotates using mod `%` makes the most sense to me.

Example: https://ideone.com/OcCLjh

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 
5 1 2 3 4 
4 5 1 2 3 
3 4 5 1 2 
2 3 4 5 1 
1 2 3 4 5
```